# Block write access to table from an application in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, security

We have a CMS plugin that writes statistics to 1 table, this creates performance issues on the entire platform. We decided to use another statistics plugin which can connect to a different database server (the first plugin couldn't!) however we need parts of the first plugin.

I want to lock the statistics table to prevent misusage (not allowed to drop it by the developer), so I was wondering if a lock table could do this or if I can implement some sort of read only table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- you could use the 'grant' command to restrict access to the table .. but the app might not like that!

no matter what you do, it would be best to prevent that plugin from writing (config options? less verbosity etc)